# how to check "Entered date is past date"

Tags: objective-c, date

I need to check whether an entered date [ taking input from user in textfield] is past date or not.

Thanks,

Sagar

Comment: Corrected your spelling.

Comment: compare: works better than the accepted answer. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/20000188-SW6) document
There are also earlierDate: and laterDate: and isEqualToDate:.

You can find the documentation on them here.

find something like:

```
if ([today laterDate:expDate] == expDate)
```

Comment: Note that `isEqualToDate:` is a very hard beast to use; unless the receiver and the argument are the same `NSDate` instance, it's doing a floating point comparison at its core so all of the standard caveats apply.

Comment: compare: works better. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert to seconds the date and then compare.
2. Use [difftime](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/difftime.html) if you can provide the parameters

There may be other methods too. Also the user should enter the time in the specified format. I would suggest to use a range of values using a drop down box or a spin widget.